# jQuery Mobile swipe over input field drags screen

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a site for a client and I stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to solve.
On the iPhone when you swipe the screen up and down to scroll it works just fine, when you have your finger over an input area and swipe, it drags the screen!

How do I solve this nasty bugger?

[image: SOTT]

[Link to website](http://sott.eu01.aws.af.cm)